# Google Bigquery on reddit database to get post along with all the comments

Tags: database, web-scraping, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am new to Google Big-query, I want to extract post title,post body,comments, score and the creation date from the database for all posts that are created on or after 2010 for a subreddit, for now I have been able to query all subreddit comments using

```
SELECT * FROM `pushshift.rt_reddit.comments` WHERE lower(subreddit)="politics"
```

But my motive is to join the comments and posts table in order to generate the required results but I am not able to find how to do this, how can that be achieved? Please let me know if any further details are required. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick note ... the tables you reference seemed to stop @ 2018-08-27 06:59:08 UTC  - meaning you may need to find another datasource if you're looking for more recent posts/comments.

Standard SQL :

```
SELECT
  s.title,
  s.selftext,
  s.score,
  s.created_utc post_created_utc,
  s.author,
  ARRAY_AGG( STRUCT( c.body,
      c.created_utc,
      c.author ) ) comments
FROM
  `pushshift.rt_reddit.submissions` s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  `pushshift.rt_reddit.comments` c
ON
  CAST(s.id AS string) = c.link_id
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(c.subreddit, r'(?i)^politics$')
  AND s.created_utc > '2009-12-31'
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5
LIMIT
  10;
```

Date SQL :

```
SELECT
  MAX(created_utc)
FROM
  `pushshift.rt_reddit.submissions`
```

Code for fh-bigquery.reddit_comments ... works the same. Maybe use this post 2018 and earlier code pre 2018.

```
    SELECT
  s.title,
  s.selftext,
  s.score,
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(s.created_utc )  post_created_utc,
  s.author,
  c.subreddit,
  ARRAY_AGG( STRUCT( c.body,
      c.created_utc,
      c.author ) ) comments
FROM
  `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.20*` s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.20*`  c
ON
regexp_extract(c.link_id,r'(.{6})\s*$') = s.id
WHERE
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(s.created_utc ) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-03' 
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6
LIMIT
  10;
```

Comment: Do you have any idea on fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.2008 data source, this DB has different tables for each year after 2015 any idea how to deal with the joins in this scenario?

Comment: You can use a [wildcard to query tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables) with the same prefix names. For example, to query the comments tables: `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.20*`

Comment: This is same query just made to work the fh-bigquery datasets :-)  SELECT
  s.title,
  s.selftext,
  s.score,
  s.created_utc post_created_utc,
  s.author,
  c.subreddit,
  ARRAY_AGG( STRUCT( c.body,
      c.created_utc,
      c.author ) ) comments
FROM
  `fh-bigquery.reddit_posts.20*` s
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  `fh-bigquery.reddit_comments.20*`  c
ON
regexp_extract(c.link_id,r'(.{6})\s*$') = s.id
WHERE
  TIMESTAMP_SECONDS(s.created_utc ) between '2019-01-01' and '2019-01-03' 
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5,
  6
LIMIT
  10;

Comment: Thank you so much it really helps!